An SF novel with whole pages entirely in capital letters
I read this SF novel decades ago.
I remember almost nothing of the events. But there were several POV characters. I don't remember how many, but all but one were human, or, possibly, "human-sized" aliens.
But there was a very unique POV "character" of an entirely different order of magnitude. It could and did indeed destroy planets, maybe even stars. A very salient detail, the only one I remember, is that all the parts seen from that POV were entirely written IN CAPITALS.
I do not remember any more details of the story. But I have a feeling that the author is a very well-known one, a "classic". I just cannot remember who !

I don't think it destroyed any planets or stars, but in Startide Rising they disturb some deep ancient species called Karrank% which communicates with them psychically.  Karrank% speech is represented in capital letters.  But definitely not whole pages; only a few lines at a time, angry and pained.

@Basya   No Karrank% has been uplifted by a different species. No way my "character" was on the same level as even the most powerful of David Brin's creatures. It is on a different level altogether., by order of magnitudes.

Yeah,  I thought it was a long shot; that's why I put it in a comment and not an answer....good luck finding the right one!

Not Science Fiction, but Death in the Pratchett novels...

Thanks, but no. It was SF, and not at all in Discworld.

This description has a weak match to Vernor Vinge's "A Fire Upon the Deep": The main characters are human-scale, the Blight matches the order-of-magnitude-greater character description, and there are pages set in fixed-width ("typewriter") font that present "Usenet"-style messages being sent around the galaxy and give a wider sense of perspective on the events in the story.

Alternatively, Iain M. Banks' "Excession" has characters at human scale and much greater scale, and has some of the AI conversations set in all caps.

@RHL I remember "A Fire upon the Deep"  This is the story with the "tines". It is not the same one. Where can I read "Excession", to compare it with my memories ?

@RLH I just read Excession  "Plot summary" on Wikipedia. Are there whole pages,in that book that are on the point of view of Excession ,and are those pages, and only those, in capital letters  ?

Well that took some finding! I'm pretty sure the novel you remember is Up the Walls of the World by James Tiptree Jr.



Known as the Destroyer, a self-aware leviathan roams through space gobbling up star systems. In its path is the planet Tyree, populated by telepathic wind-dwelling aliens who are facing extinction. Meanwhile on Earth, people burdened with psi powers are part of a secret military experiment run by a drug-addicted doctor struggling with his own grief. These vulnerable humans soon become the target of the Tyrenni, whose only hope of survival is to take over their bodies and minds - an unspeakable crime in any other period of the aliens’ history.

The superpowerful alien is called the Destroyer. We get whole chapters from its point of view and those chapters are indeed in uppercase. For example chapter one is:

COLD, COLD AND ALONE, THE EVIL PRESENCE ROAMS THE STARSTREAMS. IT IS IMMENSE AND DARK AND ALMOST IMMATERIAL: ITS POWERS ARE BEYOND THOSE OF ANY OTHER SENTIENT THING.
AND IT IS IN PAIN.
THE PAIN, IT BELIEVES, SPRINGS FROM ITS CRIME.
ITS CRIME IS NOT MURDER: INDEED, IT MURDERS WITHOUT THOUGHT. THE SIN WHICH SHAMES AND ACHES IN EVERY EDDY OF ITS ENORMOUS BEING IS DEFALCATION FROM THE TASK OF ITS
RACE.
ALONE OF ITS RACE IT HAS CONCEIVED THE CRIMINAL ACT OF SKIPPING LINK, OF DRIFTING AWAY IN PURSUIT OF NAMELESS THIRSTS. ITS TRUE NAME TOLLS UPON THE TIME-BANDS, BUT TO ITSELF IT IS THE EVIL ONE.
FROM THE DEBRIS AROUND THE CENTRAL FIRES OF THIS STARSWARM IT HEARS THE VOICES OF ITS RACE REVERBERATE AMONG THE LITTLE SUNS SUMMONING EACH TO THE CONFIGURATIONS OF
POWER. DEFEND—DESTROY, DESTROY! ALONE, IT DOES NOT, CAN NOT OBEY SOLITARY AND HUGE, IT SAILS OUT ALONG THE DUSTY ARMS, A HURTING ENTITY SLIGHTLY DENSER THAN A VACUUM ON THE CURRENTS OF SPACE-VAST, BLACK, POTENT, AND LETHAL.


Definitely the right answer. I have to wait a few hours before granting you the bounty, but of course I'll do it as soon as I can.

@Alfred It took me hours and hours to hunt that down! But I have to say that my sense of satisfaction having finally found it is enormous :-)

I'm happy to have given you that satisfaction ! Six more hours to wait for your bounty. Not my fault...

Wow, nice find. Tiptree is one of my favorite short story authors, but I've never read her novels, and certainly not this one.

According the TV Tropes CAPS LOCK article, Inquisition War has The Emperor always speaking in all-caps to indicate how powerful he was. For example:


The immense, soaring, tube-ridged throne resembled some fossilised, metastasised sloth crafted by some mad master of the Adeptus Titanicus. And it seemed to Jaq, though he did not know whether what he saw was true, or mere delusion instilled by that same psyker- dream, that this enormous, sacred prosthetic device, more precious by far than any gold, framed the wizened, mummified face of the God-Emperor.
Who looked not; though he saw through eyes of the mind, saw far beyond his throne room and his palace and the solar system. Who breathed not; yet he lived more fiercely than any mortal, enduring a psychically supercharged life-in-death.
WE ARE CURIOUS, came a mighty, anguished thought which itself transcended time.
WE HAVE FOLLOWED YOUR INTRUSION INTO OUR SANCTU- ARY, OUR ANTRUM AND ADYTUM.
'My lord.' Jaq sank to his knees. I beg to report to you before I am destroyed. I may have uncovered a major conspiracy-'
THEN WE WILL STRIP YOUR SOUL BARE. RELAX, MORTAL MAN, OR YOU WILL SURELY DIE IN SUCH PAIN AS WE ALWAYS ENDURE


Again, thanks but no. It was not a human, however powerful. It was a planet-destroying entity.

Ah... and I realize now, after finding a copy, that it looks like it is just his dialogue.

I looked at all 6 entries in the "literature" section of the TV tropes CAP LOCK. None fit ,sorry.
